# can Shapeless a good resource for extend properties in a request object finagle Service

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm coming from clojure/pedestal and something than I like is could extend the properties in a context object, context are a bit similar to middlewares and filter

```
            intercep 1           int 2
--> context -----------> context --------> context  ---> controller
     request              request           request
                          user: "tom"       user:"tom"  
                                            admin : true
```

the initial context includes the request and 
in every interceptor I add new data to the context, for instance check the session and get the user-details based in its cookies (int 1) or get if he's admin (inter 2)...when the data come to the controller it includes useful information

I know the static limitation but I think than maybe it's possible using shapeless..for instance, in my finatra controller I would like something like...

```
type SuperRequest = ......
maybe would need some implicit heres

get("/hi") { request: SuperRequest =>

info("hi")
"Hello!!  " + request.myHlist.get("name")
```

}

I think than the benefit would be a better composition because object doesnt compose well

```
   .filter(filter1)  //without HList I'd need create a new SuperRequest here with the user name
   .filter(filter2) //and here other new object with the admin details
```

could be it a good approach? do you know a better alternative for extends the object in a composable way...